# Why does an ampersand in URL cause failure of some command in Mac OS X Terminal?

Tags: macos, bash

Why does an ampersand in URL cause failure of the following command?

I want to open a web page by running Safari in Terminal, placing the URL as an argument.

This works as expected:

```
open -a safari "http://endic.naver.com/search.nhn?sLn=en&searchOption=all&query=good"
```

But once the quotes being removed, it wouldn't work as expected:

```
open -a safari http://endic.naver.com/search.nhn?sLn=en&searchOption=all&query=good
```

Instead, it returns:

```
[3] 5395
[4] 5396
[1]   Done                    open -a safari http://endic.naver.com/search.nhn?sLn=en
[2]   Done                    searchOption=all
```

Seems like ampersand in the URL was treated as "running previous command in the background", though there is no space following the ampersand in the URL.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The ampersand is a command delimiter (similar to the semicolon `;`), but indicates that the command is to be run in the background.

> If  a  command is terminated by the control operator &, the shell executes the command in the background in a subshell.  The shell does not wait for the command to finish, and the return status is 0.  Commands separated by a ; are executed sequentially; the shell waits for each command to terminate in turn.  The return status is the exit status of the last command executed

Therefore you ran three commands:

- `open -a safari "http://endic.naver.com/search.nhn?sLn=en` in the background
- `searchOption=all` in the background
- `query=good` in the foreground

The latter two are simply variable assignments, so no error was displayed (as is often the case when this happens accidentally).

---

> though there is no space following the ampersand in the URL.

This isn't needed for either `&` or `;` to end a command:

```
$ ls;pwd
Applications Desktop      Documents    Downloads    Library      Movies       Music
Pictures     Projects     Public       Work
/Users/danielbeck
```